# How to read url parameters in a redux container component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I have a react/redux application that has the following valid routes:

- https://url/product/
- https://url/product/product_id

Both Routes point to the same container component: ProductContainer. The only difference between the two urls is when the product id is supplied the application needs to fetch some data from the server and prepopulate some forms. Therefore I need some mechanism for conditionally supplying props based on the url parameters

I can get this to work - but its quite hacky/inelegant: The way I currently do it is by accessing the url string with the createhistory() object and performing some string operations on the hash to extract a product id. I was wondering if there's a cleaner, more standard way of accomplishing this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of your component you should've access to `this.props.match` and then to access the url parameter you can do `this.props.match.params.product_id`

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this method as to access this.props.match the component needs to be wrapped with the `withRouter` HOC - i.e. I can't really use that in the *container* components but more so have to use it in a child of the container component and pass it back up. Although at the moment its looking like the best possible option